# Two Equivalent Series for $ \ln(x^2+4)$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I was asked to find the corresponding series for the function $\ln(x^2+4)$

The obvious solution to me was to use the well known fact $$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$
And substituting $x^2+3$ for $x$
$$\ln(1+(x^2+3))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(x^2+3)^n}{n}$$
Using binomial theorem on the $(x^2+3)^n$ on the inside gives us the nested summation
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}\sum_{m=0}^n {n\choose{m}}x^{2m}3^{n-m}=S_1$$

However, the answer key gives the series as
$$S_2=\ln 4+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+2}}{2^{2n+2}(n+1)}$$

Question: Is $S_1=S_2$? If so, how do we prove this? If not, where is the error in this reasoning?

Thanks

Comment: Ever heard about _radius of convergence_?

Comment: I think your error is $x^2+3 > 1$. To use the $\ln(1+x)$, $x$ must be between $-1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: 
$$
4+x^2=4\left(1+\frac{x^2}{4}\right)
$$
and $\ln ab=\ln a+\ln b$.

Answer (score 0):

The series
$$\ln(1+t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{t^n}n$$
is only valid for $|t|<1$. You apply it for $t=x^2+3$. I don't
think $|x^2+3|<1$.

Comment: Is there any possible way for the series to equal each other? Like analytic continuation or something?